# TiledSprite not working as expected

Tags: android, andengine

I can't seem to get TiledSprite to work as I expect. There are no manuals, and the examples in AndEngineExamples is of no help.

Consider this code:

```
@Override
public void onLoadResources() {
  BitmapTextureAtlasTextureRegionFactory.setAssetBasePath("gfx/");
  mBlockAtlas = new BitmapTextureAtlas(512, 512, TextureOptions.BILINEAR_PREMULTIPLYALPHA);
  mBlockTexture = BitmapTextureAtlasTextureRegionFactory.createTiledFromAsset(mBlockAtlas, getApplicationContext(), "num_plasma.png", 0, 0, 3, 3);

  getTextureManager().loadTexture(mBlockAtlas);
}
```

This loads a 512x512 texture that I've - manually - divided into 3x3 tiles just for testing purposes. Now, doing this:

```
public Scene onLoadScene() {
  mScene = new Scene();
  mScene.setBackground(new ColorBackground(0.5f, 0.1f, 0.6f));

  TiledSprite foo, foo2;
  foo = new TiledSprite(0, 0, mBlockTexture);
  foo.setCurrentTileIndex(1);
  foo2 = new TiledSprite(0, 200, mBlockTexture);
  foo2.setCurrentTileIndex(5);
  mScene.attachChild(foo);
  mScene.attachChild(foo2);

  return mScene;
}
```

This puts up two sprites on the screen (as expected), but they both shows the same tile (5)!

How are one supposed to do if you have a bunch of sprites using the same texture but showing different tiles?

[image: Screenshot of error]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you need to deepCopy() the Texture when you are creating the Sprites, like

```
foo2 = new TiledSprite(0, 200, mBlockTexture.deepCopy());
```

Comment: Thanks, that helped it. Using deepCopy() for my 60+ sprites will sure hog a lot of memory, so I'm thinking of using TextureRegionFactory.extractFromTexture(), but that method wants a Texture and my texture is a TextureRegion. Do you have any clue how to make this work?

Comment: I've not used TextureRegionFactory, but TextureRegion extends BaseTextureRegion which has a getter for getTexture()

Comment: You are truly a time saver. Thanks!